# Firebase - Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore for my project and it seems to have some collection reference error.

ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. at new FirestoreError (localhost:4200/vendor.js:66703:28)

Iv' used Angular Firebase in the past and it seems like I'm doing the same thing as I did last time.

my query is very simple and its looks like that

```
public getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('users').valueChanges();
  }
```

I didnt make any changes for the Database rules

```
   service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea why is that keep hapening?

Answer (score 6):

You could change 'false' to 'true'.
It will allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
but **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
anyone to overwrite your entire database.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Very dangerous. DO NOT FOLLOW THIS SOLUTION AT ANY COST.

Answer (score 3):

You need change the Database rules if you like allow all permissions to everyone. (It's unsafe, recommended only for development environment.)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

if you need read and write in the database only for login users.

More informatión https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Answer (score 1):

/databases/users can't possibly be the path of a collection in your database, since collections can only have an odd number of path components.  What you have right now looks like a document reference.

If you have a collection called "users", then the collection reference just looks like this:

```
this.afs.collection('users')
```

"databases" is not part of that path.  That's just used with security rules.

Comment: You are right, but I also tried just 'users' and keep getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure it's the exact same error?  Your security rules are also rejecting all access from apps.  That would generate a different message.

Comment: ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:66703:28)

This is the error now

Comment: Yeah, that's a different problem.  As I said, your security rules are rejecting all access.  Change the false to true, but bear in mind that allows everyone to read the entire contents of your database.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment above said, 
I've  changed the false to true in the database rules

Comment: Bear in mind here that your question had TWO problems.  The first was an incorrect path, which created the error message in the question before you edited it.  Then there was the problem with security rules.  It's expected that you not change the question unless extra information is needed.  Otherwise you invalidate the helpful answers.